# Need to run more than one commands

Tags: kubernetes

I have to run 2 commands at a time:

1. `bash`
2. `service nginx start`

How can I pass those by using the following command?

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --command -- <cmd> <arg1> ... <argN>

kubectl run -it testnew --image=imagename --command -- "/bin/bash","-c","service nginx start && while true; do echo bye; sleep 10;done" --requests=cpu=200m
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the `--command` flag works or is supposed to work.

This works for me, in that I get a running nginx with bash looping forever and printing 'bye'.
`kubectl run -it testnew --image=nginx -- /bin/bash -c "service nginx start && while true; do echo bye; sleep 10;done"`

Instead of this special command, you probably want to create a tweaked image that runs a script on start. Easier to manage what is running and harder to lose the customizations.